# Merge sort in array of structs

Tags: c, arrays, object, struct

I have an array of structs, where each object is a student with a name and a grade, and I'm trying to merge sort this array (I want to sort them by grade in ascending order).
Here is the Student Struct:

```
struct Student
{
    char grade[42];
    char city[42];
};
```

grade is a char because I assign the grade value by getting an input from the user with fgets and sscanf.
I don't think it's necessary to put my whole code of the merge-sort algorithm but I want to share this part which I think might be problematic ?

```
    int firstHalfSize = midElement - firstElement + 1;
    int secondHalfSize = lastElement - midElement;
    struct Student firstHalfArray[firstHalfSize];
    struct Student secondHalfArray[secondHalfSize];
    char *p;
    char *s;
    int index1 = 0;
    int index2 = 0;
    int mergedArrIndex = firstElement;

    while (index1 < firstHalfSize && index2 < secondHalfSize)
    {
        if (strtol(firstHalfArray[index1].grade, &p, 10) <= strtol(secondHalfArray[index2].grade, &s, 10))
        {
            arr[mergedArrIndex] = firstHalfArray[index1];
            index1++;
        }
        else
        {
            arr[mergedArrIndex] = secondHalfArray[index2];
            index2++;
        }
        mergedArrIndex++;
    }
```

the part where I sort the student object by comparing the grade is by converting the `char grade` into a long with `strtol` which I think I did good so it might not be a problem.
My problems is that I initialize my array of structs like the following:

```
struct Student students[5501];
```

and when I get a new input of the user I just add it into the array like the following:

```
struct Student aStudent;
int lineCounter = 0;
students[lineCounter] = aStudent;
```

and increase `lineCounter` by 1 every time I get a new input. (`aStudent` is changed when I get a new input)
Here I call the merge-sort function and get weird results:

```
mergeSort(students, 0, 5501); // 5501 is the size of the array
printArray(students, 5501);
```

Here is the printArray function created just to see if I get the grade in ascending order

```
void printArray(struct Student A[], int size)
{
    char *p;
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%ld", strtol(A[i].grade, &p, 10));

}
```

but I keep getting that printed:

```
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000...
```

and I don't know why.
Also how can I do that If the user adds 3 students object in the array `students`
I only treat it as like an array of 3 elements and not an array of 5501 elements ?
Thanks! And sorry if it's a little long I really tried to be concise without having a loss of essential informations.

Answer (score -1):

Since the user can input N numbers of students I recommend you to use a Linked List instead and put the node (struct Student) in his right position depending on the grade.

You can learn more about Linked Lists [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/data-structures/linked-list/).